# Bootstrap: How can I detect the state of NavBar (mobile or Desktop) in my PHP code?

Tags: php, mobile

I have seen many ways to detect if the user is on a mobile, or a desktop. That's related to my question, but not completely.

What I would like to achieve in order to make a mobile UI or a desktop one is to base my logic on the Navbar element.
This will allow more consistency in UI.

> Navbars are responsive meta components that serve as navigation
>   headers for your application or site. They begin collapsed (and are
>   toggleable) in mobile views and become horizontal as the available
>   viewport width increases.

What I mean is that this one should display my desktop UI (mainly for HTML table)
[image]

While this one will trigger the Mobile UI:

[image]

Do you know if there is a simple way to achieve that in PHP? 
Depending on the result, I will change my HTML table.

Thank a lot.

Comment: The "magic" of navbar collapsing etc happens on client side. It doesn't make sense, what you're saying. Navbar can collapse and expand in the browser when user resize browser window, therefore PHP has nothing to do here.

Comment: Imagine that you run your PHP from command line - it's impossible from PHP side to check client side parameters.

Comment: OK, impossible sounds a correct answer. You can reply, and I will accept Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using something like javascript to query the browser, then have it set the navbar id or class to "mobile" (using class might help with styling differences that occur throughout the page as opposed to individual id's), and default to "desktop".

If you strictly want to use PHP, there is the $_SERVER superglobal, which contains information about what the server knows for itself and the client. In this case, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] will report the browser specific build, which you can use an if/elseif/else block with the str_pos() function for browsers you support, based on what the superglobal has in it. Things like 'x86' and 'x86_64' are desktop architectures, whereas 'ARMvX' would be mobile processors (someone please verify if my assumption is correct here on the mobile and 32-bit architectures).

You should use actual mobile devices on the server by making a browser-check.php using the following:

```
<?php
    echo '<html><head></head><body>' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . </body></html>';
?>
```

Test it out with different browsers on differing OSes and devices, and compile a list of specifics from each browser by category and sub-category, like so:

```
<?php
    $arch = null;
    $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (strpos("Firefox", $browser) === 1) {
        if (strpos("x86;", $browser) === 1) {$arch = "desktop-32";}
        if (strpos("x86_64;", $browser) === 1) {$arch = "desktop-64";}
        if (strpos("ARM", $browser) === 1) {$arch = "mobile";}
    }
    if (strpos("Chrome", $browser) === 1) {
    ...
    }
?>
```

Hopefully, that helps you get an algorithm started on your support list of browsers. Keep in mind, I only actually checked my browser using the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], which is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
```

The 32-bit is mostly assumed that 'x86;' is in there, and I really couldn't tell you just yet what mobile firefox reports, as I don't feel like hitting my webserver with a page right now (it's undergoing some issues right now with its packages). Again, try some older and newer devices (yes, even iPhones) and see what they produce. If you want to, you can anonymously collect this data by having your page script store the entire output of $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] into a database or flatfile, then redirect the client to the page they are looking for until you are ready to make changes. This way, you can do what you will with the information, and the clients aren't specifically aware of this little browser agent data collection (it's anonymous, so it shouldn't be an issue).

Also, don't worry about people who spoof their browser's user agent, since they won't necessarily be considered legitimate users to your site if they aren't willing to properly report their browser's architecture (which coincides with their platform).

::EDIT::

I forgot, your main question is to detect whether the client is mobile or desktop by focusing your logic with the navbar element. I would specifically advise against it.

Since mobile browsers for years past have the capability to request desktop versions, despite their screen size being too small to handle it. Deciding on the navbar state (which would require something like jQuery / Ajax, php won't work without a client-side script like js reporting back) would not yield the expected result, especially if the device is a large tablet, since the screensize is going to report an HD resolution, and the navbar will act as though it were on a large HD monitor, only finer-scaled. You really don't want your tablet clients getting the desktop navbar just because it will fit on their screen, you would like to give them that familiar three-lined button that exists on most apps and websites.

So, again, I stick to my PHP and/or jQuery information collection idea prior to sending HTML to the client.